# How to sum values of a List of Maps by Java Stream API

Tags: java, arraylist, sum, java-stream

I have a `List<Map<String,Object>> resultList` (from DB Query)

like this

```
Map<String,Object>map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();        
        map1.put("01", "1");
        map1.put("02", "5");
        map1.put("03", "7");

        Map<String,Object>map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();        
        map2.put("01", "2");
        map2.put("02", "4");
        map2.put("03", "6");

        Map<String,Object>map3 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();    
        map3.put("01", "8");
        map3.put("02", "5");
        map3.put("03", "6");

        Map<String,Object>map4 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
        map4.put("01", "7");
        map4.put("02", "4");
        map4.put("03", "2");

        List<Map<String,Object>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

        mapList .add(map1);
        mapList .add(map2);
        mapList .add(map3);
        mapList .add(map4);
```

I want to use mapList to sum values groupBy key

Result what I want:

`Map<String,Integer> resultMap {01=18, 02=18, 03=21}`

I have tried many different method but cant work...

Q: How to convert Object to int in stream and sum values groupBy key?

Comment: `mapList.stream().map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.summingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().toString()))))`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you might be constraint with `Map<String, Object>`, you can do:

```
Map<String, Object> output = mapList.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue, (o1, o2) -> (int) o1 + (int) o2));
```

Though preferably, with a `Map<String, Integer>` you can use `Integer::sum` as the mere function

```
Map<String, Integer> output = mapList.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));
```

or use `groupingBy` with `summingInt` as:

```
Map<String, Integer> output = mapList.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                    Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: thank ur reply 
I used the frist method! its helpful and work.  thank u a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sum over your map generics better be Integer, so it's easy to use the sum() method, It may not be the best way, but hopefully it will help，here's my code

```
int sum  = mapList.stream()
        .mapToInt(
                map -> map.keySet().stream().mapToInt(s -> map.get(s)).sum())
        .sum();
```

Comment: because the "mapList"  was query from DB by our project  DBUtil, type cant change
 thank u ur reply ,maybe next time i can use this.